# Handling routes with express for react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react app running fine. I wanted to deploy it using express static. So i have given the express-static path to the build folder in client. The '/' routes works fine and the React router takes the job from there. But when i refresh the page, express is not able to send the build file, instead gives an error

Tried to use * all routes in express to the same react build file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/', 'build')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of writing down(duplicating) all the routes in express again, wanted a simpler solution

Comment: You need to make a router which works for the server and client afaik. Back when I did it anyway - https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js. Personally I would just use something built for the purpose like Next.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this settings :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const CLIENT_APP_PATH = '../client/build';

app.use(express.static(CLIENT_APP_PATH));

// ...express middlewares, rest, etc...

// in the end of app routing
// serves frontend application
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(`${CLIENT_APP_PATH}/index.html`), { root: __dirname }, err => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```